# Simulating time series microarray data

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, microarray

So, first I have to start with simulating time series  microarray data in R

- fixed effect-4 time point,
- random effect- array,
- pid(single observation)
- I have to add Gaussian noise and Poisson noise.

Could anyone suggest some codes in R, if it is possible.